# Difference between write and fwrite not the same results

Tags: c

If I have piece of code that writes out text like this: `write(1, buf, bytes);` why doesn't the same works for writing to a file `fwrite(1, buf, bytes,f1);`?

Where `f1` is declared as `FILE *f1;` and `f1=fopen("Test.txt", "wb");`. The tutorials I'm looking at indicate that it should work. I'm C# coder and not a C coder and would like some help with this.

Comment: write takes a filedescriptor as first parameter - not a count of bytes

Comment: Wanna be like you Jim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `fwrite` is:

```
fwrite(const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

While the signature of write is:

```
write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

If you match your examples you'll see that parameter don't match.

count of `write` should be `size*count` of `fwrite` (which let you specify the size of every element you are writing). In addition write has a file descriptor hardcoded as 1 and which you replace with a `FILE*` obtained from `fopen`, how do you know that `1` is referring to that file?

Comment: The file descriptor it f1 which is what I indicates and goes as last parameter in the fwrite call, right? What is the `* ptr` refers to? I was under the assumption that it is the actual data. If now where is the data referenced?

Comment: data is the first parameter, but in your example you have 1 in the first parameter.